# C# Linq copying values into model from different sources

Tags: c#, linq

So I come with a List list and first make it to a dictionary for faster searches.

```
Dictionary<Guid, Int32> dictionaryFromList = list
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, y => y.Item2);
```

Now Im loading all the other info in another Dictionary from the cache:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Model> modelDictionary = _cache
  .Where(x => dictionaryFromList.ContainsKey(x.Id))
  .Select(y => new {y.Id, y })
  .ToDictionary(t => t.Id, t=> t.y);
```

Now I need two different things:
1. I need to insert more data into some of the Models in the modelDictionary
2. I need to insert the Int32 from the dictionaryFromList into the modelDictionary

My approach for 1. was the following:

```
HashSet<Guid> toLoadIds = new HashSet<Guid>(modelDictionary
  .Where(x => !x.Value.IsLoaded)
  .Select(x => x.Key));

context.myTable
  .Where(x => toLoadIds.Contains(x.Id))
  .Select(x => new {x.value1, x.value2, x.value3, x.value4, x.value5, x.value6 }));
```

I selected the values now afaik but how should I get them into the right model in the modelDictionary?

For the 2. one I tried doing this:

```
dictionaryFromList.Select(y => modelDictionary[y.Key].myValue = y.Value);
```

But it seems like nothing is working properly :(

The previous solution for the 2. was the following when modelDictionary was stil a List

```
modelDictionary.ForEach(x => x.myValue = dictionaryFromList[x.AddressId]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
dictionaryFromList.Select(y => modelDictionary[y.Key].myValue = y.Value);
```

the execution is *deferred* until someone runs through the returned select iterator. But you do not pick it up, so no-one does that.

You *could* do:

```
dictionaryFromList.Select(y => modelDictionary[y.Key].myValue = y.Value)
  .LastOrDefault();
```

where the final call will force the iteration of the select iterator. But I find that ugly. Why not simply use `foreach`?

```
foreach (var y in dictionaryFromList) { modelDictionary[y.Key].myValue = y.Value; }
```